# How do I change a value of a 2D-vector?

Tags: c++

Thats how I created the 2D-Vector that I want to use as a storing unit for a bunch of letters(font):
62 Letters and 56 int variables for them each('0' and '1' used to simulate a pixel at the point where a '1' is):

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> letters(62, std::vector<int>(56, 0));
```

But how do I change a value of it?
(f.e. the value of letters[0][0] to 1?(`letters[0][0] = 1;` doesn't work(C4430, C2040, C2440)))

**EDIT: The problem was in fact somewhere else...I tried to change the value inside of a namespace...**

Comment: `letters[0][0] = 1;` should be correct.  Please [edit] yuour question to contain a [mre] and please include the exact text from the error message.

Comment: _"C4430, C2040, C2440"_ Not everyone memoizes these compiler specific error codes. Post a [mcve] including the verbatim error messages, as it's required here please!

Comment: You can copy the error messages using the output window and selecting `Build` for `Show output from`

Comment: I strongly recommend not upvoting unanswerable questions. It sends the wrong message to the asker.

Comment: Instead of editing the question to declare it answered, attempt to make it answerable. If you ask too many poorly-received questions you will be prevented from asking new questions until you manage to dig your way back out with well-received questions, and that's bvery hard to do when you're only allowed to ask questions every six months or so. Deleting poorly-received questions doesn't help because deleted questions also contribute to question bans. And currently they contribute forever, as far as anyone can tell ([a position I'd like to see softened](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/404510).

Comment: So there is probably no question left because the OP could fix it himself. What should he do in that case?

Comment: @Henk That's a exactly the problem with the "Just Fix It" philosophy. Some questions can't be fixed enough to ever be well received. You'd have to completely repurpose the question.

Comment: I do not understand you. There seems to be no question left, OP has solved the problem.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> letters(62, std::vector<int>(56, 0));
    letters[0][0]=1;
    std::cout<<letters[0][0];
}
```

This compiles and outputs 1 as wanted, so your problem seems to be somewhere else.

Comment: Is there something general wrong with this kind of answer?

Comment: This is likely to be unhelpful to both OP and future StackOverflow users. The problem here is that OP's question is incomplete. We need to know what they mean by "doesn't work." Trying to answer incomplete questions is like taking a shot in the dark.

Comment: It is showing the OP a complete program that shows how to use it such that it works. It answers the title question and also states that this is not the problem with the code. Is there some other way to provide this? You cannot really put a whole program into a comment.

Comment: That's better served as a comment.  That allows the OP to fix the question so they ask the question that actually gets them what they want.  The OP says `letters[0][0]=1;` gives them an error, so this answer doesn't help them.

Comment: Of course it does. It eliminates a possible source of error.

Comment: What I generally do with a question like this is make a code sample like yours in an online C++ sandbox like wandbox or ideone and post a comment something like *Cannot reproduce: <link>*. Gets the point across without making a non-answer answer.

Comment: @Henk Sure, we can archive all pokes in the dark here. Very useful for future research (in case you're wondering what's the reason for my downvote).

Comment: @user4581301 Okay, I agree that this is a better solution.